# Is the "Secret Policeman's Ball" an allusion to bribery?

Tags: slang, metaphors, allusion

The Secret Policeman's Ball were a series of benefit shows.

However, is the phrase "buying a ticket to the Secret Policeman's Ball" an allusion to paying a bribe?

Comment: What do you base the allusion on? Because of the word "secret"?

Comment: @mari-lou A No, that you would pay an officer for a ticket to a non-existent event and that payment is the bribe.

Comment: Maybe it's not an allusion, maybe it's a code or a shibboleth.

Comment: https://aadl.org/aapd/truecrimes/4 It appears that the Policeman's ball was always a fundraising event. I imagine one must be familiar with the Month Python sketch, if there is one... to grasp the meaning behind the British TV shows. P.S More details you add, the better, and explain why you think it was originally a standin for a bribe. IN the question, not in comments. it's +1 from me if you!

Comment: Secret policeman, means precisely that, someone who belongs the secret police of a tyrant, dictator  or authoritarian leader.  A ball is a gathering of people who pay to eat a meal and dance to a live band, I found nothing that supports your idea. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition - everyone knows that if there's a knock on the door in the middle of the night, it'll be the Secret (Police) Service.

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Month Python? Is that the show with the Silly March?

Comment: @BillJ I saw a comic years ago with someone paying for a ticket and that seemed to be the only joke in it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sorry, Sir.  It was only a typo. Obviously, I meant Monty Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Although you might be confusing two different uses.

The Secret Policeman's Ball was an Amnesty International show, like a Broadway show.

It got its name from a running joke in British culture at the time that said if you got pulled over by the police, you could offer to buy a couple of tickets to the Policeman's Ball and bribe your way out of the infraction.

See [this article](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/secret-policemans-ball_b_1318876) for more information.

Comment: AHA! I KNEW IT!!